# Share semantics actions in bison

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bison

Is it possible to have the same semantic action execute for multiple rules in bison?

i.e. I have something like

```
exp: NUM            { $$ = $1; }
   | exp exp        { $$ = $1; }
```

Would it be possible to get away with writing only one action?

Comment: Not when it is as minimal as that — no.  If the actions are a bit bigger, you can do it with carefully crafted function calls, but assignment to $$ usually ends up being done in the action (`{ $$ = semantics_xyz($1, $2, $3); }`).  And it might be argued that since `$$ = $1` is the default, maybe you don't need anything in this specific context — but you do in the general context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
list: exp { $$ = $1; }
exp : NUM
    | exp exp
```